# (JunOs Configuration) setting eBGP for l3vpn

Tags: mpls-vpn

i'have one line configuration eBGP to peering PE routers with CE router. anyone can explain this configuration? i'm very confuse. thanks before :)

**set routing-instances xxxxx bgp group ebgp export EXP-Direct-static-bgp**

Answer (score 1):

That configuration statement is applying an export policy named `EXP-Direct-static-bgp` to a BGP based PE-CE connection.  You can look at what the policy does by issuing:

`show configuration policy-options policy-statement EXP-Direct-static-bgp`